# tikz: relocatable rotatable colorable objects with example (but no fill)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I admit that I am posting this partly because tikz is so cool.  Experimentation with the .pic feature shows how one can define a simple object, and place it anywhere in the plot, scaled, rotated, etc.  The only part that I do not understand is why fill does not seem to be picked up.  It could be my mistake or a limitation of pic.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\def\centerarc[#1](#2)(#3:#4:#5)% [draw options] (center) (initial angle:final angle:radius)
{ \draw[#1] ($(#2)+({#5*cos(#3)},{#5*sin(#3)})$) arc (#3:#4:#5); }

\tikzset{
  speaker/.pic={
    \draw (-1,-0.5) -- (0,-0.5) -- (1,-1.5) -- (1,1.5) -- (0,0.5) -- (-1,0.5) -- (-1,-0.5);
    % sound waves
    \centerarc[red,thin](1,0)(-60:60:0.5);
    \centerarc[thin](1,0)(-60:60:1);
    \centerarc[red,thin](1,0)(-60:60:1.5);
  }
}

\noindent%
\fbox{
  \begin{tikzpicture}

    \draw[step=1, lightgray, very thin] (-1,-1) grid (11,11);
    \node[draw] at (0,0) {\tiny 0,0};
    \node[draw] at (10,10) {\tiny 10,10};

    \pic at (5,5) {speaker};

    \pic[rotate=90] at (2,2) {speaker};

    \pic[rotate=135,scale=0.5] at (2,7) {speaker};

    \pic[rotate=135,scale=0.5,blue, fill=yellow] at (7,2) {speaker};

  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{document}
```

[image: illustrated speaker diagram]

Comment: Your code will not compile without modification.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pic actions` to tell some or all actions within your `pic` definition to use options passed with the `\pic` command. For example:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\def\centerarc[#1](#2)(#3:#4:#5)% [draw options] (center) (initial angle:final angle:radius)
{\draw[#1] ($(#2)+({#5*cos(#3)},{#5*sin(#3)})$) arc (#3:#4:#5);}
\tikzset{%
  speaker/.pic={%
    \draw [pic actions] (-1,-0.5) -- (0,-0.5) -- (1,-1.5) -- (1,1.5) -- (0,0.5) -- (-1,0.5) -- (-1,-0.5);
    % sound waves
    \centerarc[red, thin, pic actions](1,0)(-60:60:0.5);
    \centerarc[thin, pic actions](1,0)(-60:60:1);
    \centerarc[red, thin, pic actions](1,0)(-60:60:1.5);
  }
}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \draw[step=1, lightgray, very thin] (-1,-1) grid (11,11);
  \node[draw] at (0,0) {\tiny 0,0};
  \node[draw] at (10,10) {\tiny 10,10};

  \pic at (5,5) {speaker};

  \pic[rotate=90] at (2,2) {speaker};

  \pic[rotate=135,scale=0.5] at (2,7) {speaker};

  \pic[rotate=135,scale=0.5,blue, fill=yellow] at (7,2) {speaker};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: pic actions]

or

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\def\centerarc[#1](#2)(#3:#4:#5)% [draw options] (center) (initial angle:final angle:radius)
{\draw[#1] ($(#2)+({#5*cos(#3)},{#5*sin(#3)})$) arc (#3:#4:#5);}
\tikzset{%
  speaker/.pic={%
    \draw [pic actions] (-1,-0.5) -- (0,-0.5) -- (1,-1.5) -- (1,1.5) -- (0,0.5) -- (-1,0.5) -- (-1,-0.5);
    % sound waves
    \centerarc[red, thin](1,0)(-60:60:0.5);
    \centerarc[thin](1,0)(-60:60:1);
    \centerarc[red, thin](1,0)(-60:60:1.5);
  }
}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \draw[step=1, lightgray, very thin] (-1,-1) grid (11,11);
  \node[draw] at (0,0) {\tiny 0,0};
  \node[draw] at (10,10) {\tiny 10,10};

  \pic at (5,5) {speaker};

  \pic[rotate=90] at (2,2) {speaker};

  \pic[rotate=135,scale=0.5] at (2,7) {speaker};

  \pic[rotate=135,scale=0.5,blue, fill=yellow] at (7,2) {speaker};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: limited pic actions]